# For what points $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $f$ continuous?

Tags: analysis, continuity, proof-verification

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R} $ be a fintie set and define $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=1$ is $x \in X$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. At which points $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ continuous?

My Attempted Solution;
If we define $X:=\{a,b\}$ where $a<b \ \ \ a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.
I claim that $f$ is continuous at all points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except at points $a \ \ and \ \ b$.

$$\lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x)=0 \ \ and \ \ \lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x)=1$$
So $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq f(a)$ and $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.
Similarly;
$$\lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x)=1 \ \ and \ \ \lim_{x \to b^{+}}f(x)=0$$
So $ \lim_{x \to b} f(x) \neq f(b)$ and $f$ is discontinuous at $b$.

Ia this solution correct?Any corrections \advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: $X:=[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not a finite set at all, is it? Do you mean $X:=\{a,b\}$?

Comment: Yes you are correct my apologies

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous at all points in $\mathbb{R} - X$.

The reasoning in your example is incorrect. The left and right limits are the same.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^{-}} f(x) = 0$

However $f(a) = 1$. Hence $f$ is not continuous at $a$ since the limit and the actual value of the function does not agree.

Comment: so $f$ is discontinuous for all $x \in X$?

Comment: @Kimo Yes. Your claim is correct.

Comment: and why is the limit as x approaches $a$ from the right 0, not 1?? Sorry if it seems obvious

Comment: @Kimo This is because for all $x > a$ (so long as $x$ does not exceed b if $a < b$), one has $f(x) = 0$. In other words, in a sufficiently small neighborhood to the right of $a$, the value of $f$ is always $0$.

Comment: But the question says that for all x>a f(x)=1. Shouldn't the neighbourhood right of $a$ be 1? assuming x doesn't exceed b?

Comment: @Kimo As Piwi mentioned in the comments, I assumed you meant $X = \{a,b\}$, and not the intervale $[a,b]$ since it is not a finite set.

Comment: oh! I was taking X as an interval not a set apologies @William . You are 100% correct, thank you for your time